# GearVR WebVR Samsung Browser - viewing JS console output

Tags: virtual-reality, webvr, gear-vr, samsung-browser

I'm trying to view the JavaScript console output of a WebVR scene, that's being loaded in the Samsung GearVR browser. If it was in the Chrome browser I could use some form of remote debugging, but with the Samsung browser that wouldn't work.

I looked around the web, but nothing mentioned the particular Samsung Browser WebVR debugging situation.

Does anyone have any ideas or links?
I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Did the answer below help? If so please could you mark it as the correct answer? There's also more info here: https://samsunginter.net/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: I wasnt able to connect to com.sec.android.app.svrbrowser using chrome on GNU/Linux, sbrowser is fine tough...

https://github.com/SamsungInternet/blog/blob/master/content/pages/docs/remote-debugging.md

Answer (score 2):

Actually, chrome remote debugging works on Samsung Internet for GearVR. Just connect adb through wifi (GearVR USB won't work, it's charging only), open `chrome://inspect` in the desktop chrome and when the headset is active, the page should be visible on the list. All active webkit instances are on that list, not only Chrome. For example you can also sniff gmail app html views.

For this to work, you have to have the headset's screen active - it's hard to have it on your head while debugging so I suggest you use some paper sticky tape to cover the sensor that is between the lenses.